# Regarding custom builds in Ember

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, build, broccolijs

How do I extend my custom environment (and build), for example, "staging" from `production`?

Ultimately I want to do `ember build --environment=staging`, reap the goodness and optimization provided by "production" build + want to provide some custom config.

Comment: you can make use of env. variables like `DEPLOYMENT=staging ember build --environment=production` and do any custom config thing using the `process.env.DEPLOYMENT` variable inside `ember-cli-build.js`

Answer (score 2):

This is harder to do than it probably should be and isn't recommended as I hope providing some instructions will make clear. The first step is to modify your `config/environment.js` file with whatever customization you want. Might look like

```
if (environment === 'staging') {
 //set something
}
```

But then you have to deal with other things that `production` brings to the table automatically. For example fingerprinting of assets is only done in production so you have to modify `emebr-cli-build.js` to add some instructions to make `staging` like `production`.

```
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  const env = EmberApp.env() || 'development';
  const isProductionLikeBuild = ['production', 'staging'].indexOf(env) > -1;

  const app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    fingerprint: { enabled: isProductionLikeBuild },
    sourcemaps: { enabled: isProductionLikeBuild },
    minifyCSS: { enabled: isProductionLikeBuild },
    minifyJS: { enabled: isProductionLikeBuild },

    tests: env.EMBER_CLI_TEST_COMMAND || !isProductionLikeBuild,
```

There are probably more things that `production` does, but those are the ones I know about.

Another place to look is in `config/targets.js` where you will find the line `const isProduction = process.env.EMBER_ENV === 'production';` which needs to be changed for your new environment as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [ember-cli-deploy](http://ember-cli-deploy.com/). It essentially lets you create deploy "targets" that can have different environmental variables and what not, while giving you the benefit of minified files, fingerprinting, etc. that's included in Ember's production build.